# How can I auto tweet any node of a specific type to Twitter?

Tags: 7, social-network

I know the Twitter module lets you setup automatic tweets of new content to your twitter account, but I am wondering how/if its possible to schedule automatic tweets of old content as well.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this with Rules, Rules Bonus Pack, Views, Flag & Twitter Modules.

Set up a Rule that is:

1. Triggered during Cron runs.
2. Has no conditions
3. Loads a list of Node IDs from Views (Rules Bonus Pack)
4. Posts to twitter based on the first NID in the view.

For my view, I made a flag called Tweet This attached to my node type, and the view displays nodes that have this flag.  You could use a different method to grab the list of nodes you want to tweet, such as filtering by date posted (get older content based on a given date) or number of views (popularity).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using [hook_cron()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) function.

```
function mymodule_cron() {

    // Find all the node which are not tweeted yet.

   // Check the twitter module and look for the code which performs tweet of newly created node. I would have posted code but not able to access right now

   // Use this code and tweet this nodes

   // This will tweet old nodes which are not tweeted yet

}
```

Comment: Can you explain more. Like How to use cron to make auto-post of old contents ? What is the cron interval ? Cant it be done with a page ?

Comment: Thanks.  Although I did end up doing it with Rules.